# Symfony2 - I can't get gmail mail transport get to work ... authentication fails

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I have a mailer configuration based on http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/gmail.html but when I'm sending the email from custom symfony console command I'm getting this error:

[2015-03-16 20:38:09] app.ERROR: Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "?????????" using 1 possible authenticators

I tried two gmail accounts for authentiaction but no luck ... Any idea whats wrong here?

**SOLVED: The problem was this**
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en ... I simply enabled it ...

Comment: Which config file did you modify and what is the format of your symfony console command? Specifically, are you declaring an `--env=dev` or `--env=prod` flag explicitly anywhere, or lack thereof?

Comment: --env=dev ... instead of ??? the error message shows the proper username (email address) from dev configuration ...

Comment: Does your Gmail account have two-factor authentication enabled?

Comment: No two factor auth. enabled...

Comment: I've [made a proposed edit to the docs you've referenced to prevent this confusion in the future](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/5085). Would you mind posting your solution as an answer here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credit to @David Marko:

You have either to upgrade to a more secure app that uses the most up to date security measures. All Google products, like Gmail, use the latest security measures. (https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

Or to Allow less secure apps and choose “Allow” to let less secure apps access your Google account. We don't recommend this option because it may make it easier for someone to gain access to your account.

Source : https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en